# What would be natural to insert in the example?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction

Jack starts coughing. He tries to hold it back, but can't.

Elsewhere in the house, the police office can hear _________________(1) He follows _________________(2).

(1)  Jack's coughing/Jack coughing/The coughing/The sound of coughing.

(2)  The coughing/The sound of coughing.

Which of the above suggestions would be natural to insert in the two places in the example?

I think: If (a) is both "Jack's coughing" and "Jack coughing" possible? For (2) in my example, is it natural to write "He follows the coughing"?

Comment: What do you think is correct? One idea that may help you decide: Does the police officer (a) know that Jack is in the house or (b) do they initially think the house is empty or (c) do they think some unknown person is in the house or (d) something else?

Comment: If (a) is both "Jack's coughing" and "Jack coughing" possible? For (2) in my example, is it natural to write "He follows the coughing"?

Answer (score 1):

This question can be covered in different ways.
When you say: *heard Jack coughing* - he coughed more than once.
*"Jack's coughing"* would be a noun phrase, and to my ear a slightly more formal option. Even the choice *"heard Jack cough"* isn't wrong - which implies Jack has coughed once.

Bare infinitive - single occurrence of an action

Progressive - an action that has happened more than once

**Both sound natural in this context with a difference in meaning.** Though that wasn't the primary question, it may be helpful. Note that *"a sound of coughing/a cough"* would mean almost the same as the bare infinitive example - except it might not have been Jack who coughed.

**Now, my pick for the second blank will be *"the sound" or "it"*.** It's concise, and the article makes it clear that the sound is coming from Jack's coughing. Keep in mind if you previously chose the line *"a sound of coughing/a cough",* you would refer to the same cough/coughing. As I said before, the sound wouldn't be from Jack's coughing - we don't know who coughed.

**Out of context, "he follows the coughing" can be acceptable but "to follow a sound" is a common expression.**

Comment: I would recommend writing it this way: _Now, my pick for the second blank will be "the sound" or "it"._ Because many people might get confused between the choices.

Answer (score 0):

If the police officer knows that Jack is in the house then either of the first two phrases is fine. I cannot see any difference here between "Jack's coughing" and "Jack coughing".

If the police officer does not know that it is Jack in the house then I would say the the police office can hear the coughing and he follows its sound. The full "he follows the sound of coughing" is not wrong but uses more words than is necessary.